# Ubuntu too slow in new laptop

Tags: boot, 14.04, acer

I just bought an acer aspire E5-521-62DW - NX.MPQEB.001

It has 12Gb ram, 1 TB hdd, AMD A6-6310 processor (4 kernels, 4 threads), AMD Radeon R4 graphics.

It takes more than 1 and a half minute to start, and every application starts really slow. Chromium for example, when I type some text it takes around two seconds to appear. And the touchpad is'nt working...

Do you know if maybe my new laptop is not compatible with ubuntu 14.04 or what could be happening?

Answer (score 1):

In order to make your system faster, you could try the following:

- Install the proprietary AMD driver, so the APU speed can be regulated.

  Open *Software & Updates*, go to *Additional drivers* and select *fglrx*.
- Install the packages *preload* and *prelink*. These take certain actions to make the system faster.

  Execute `sudo apt-get install prelink preload` in a terminal.
- Reduce Swap usage. The default *swappiness* value is 60, which may be too high.

  Open the file `/etc/sysctl.conf` and set the swappiness parameter:
  `sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf` in a terminal.
  New line at the end: `vm.swappiness = 10`, then another linebreak, save with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>.
- Enable boot profiling. The next reboot may take a bit longer, but the following should be faster.

  Open `/etc/default/grub` and append `profile` to the line that says `quiet splash`:

  ```
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash profile"
  ```

  If you don't want your boot menu to appear (if it even does), set `GRUB_TIMEOUT=0`

  Save, exit and run `sudo update-grub`.

If you apply these changes, your computer should get faster after a reboot.

For your touchpad, you should ask a new question, since this is another problem.